# How to specify boundary string with AFHTTPSessionManager?

Tags: afnetworking, boundary

Seems that AFHTTPSessionManager will set a random boundary string. But the server I am accessing will verify this boundary string to determine whether it is legal request.
Can I set specify this boundary string?